# Spring data with @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn throws Exception

Tags: java, spring, jpa, inheritance, spring-data-jpa

I use Spring data jpa and I have two Entities that have inheritance relationship.

Here is the parent.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name = "creditcardinfo")
@DiscriminatorColumn
public class CreditCardInfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="credit_card_info_id")
    private int creditCardInfoId;
```

And here is the child

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("tappay")
@Table(name = "tappaycardinfo")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "credit_card_info_id",referencedColumnName = "credit_card_info_id")
public class TappayCardInfo extends CreditCardInfo implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "card_token")
    private String cardToken;

    @Column(name = "card_key")
    private String cardKey;
```

And I use JpaRepository to CRUD. Here's my repository.

```
public interface TappayCardInfoDAO extends JpaRepository<TappayCardInfo, Integer>
```

I always got an Exception when I saved my TappayCardInfo.

```
@Inject private TappayCardInfoDAO tappayCardInfoDAO;
...
tappayCardInfoDAO.save(cardInfo);
```

Here's error message.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The entity must have one and only one property with id annotation, class name: base.model.TappayCardInfo

Comment: The default is to use the same name for ID fields when using joined inheritance, so the PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation isn't needed.  Does it work if you remove it?  You might turn on logging in your JPA provider to see if it gives any other indication of why it might think there are two IDs defined for the entity.

Comment: @Chris It dosen't work. I remove it and the exception still occour